# iPhone Notification when Phone rings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new in iPhone programming. so please tell me Can we get the notification when the phone rings and answer the Phone? If Yes then How?anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

If an iOS app is in the foreground and has set an audio interrupt handler in the app's Audio Session setup, then that handler will get called when the phone rings.  If the call is accepted, then the app will be notified that it is being sent to the background.  If not, then the audio session handler will be called again to allow the app's audio to be restarted.  If an app is not running in the foreground, or does not have an active audio session, it is not possible to get any notification.